# Extracting CSV from Export Button

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I apologize for not being able to specifically give out the url im dealing with.  I'm trying to extract some data from a certain site but its not organized well enough.  However, they do have an "Export To CSV file" and the code for that block is ...

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ExportValueCSVButton" value="Export to Value CSV" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ExportValueCSVButton" class="smallbutton">
```

In this type of situation, whats the best way to go about grabbing that data when there is no specific url to the CSV, Im using Mechanize and BS4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're able to click a button that could download the data as a csv, it sounds like you might be able to `wget link` that data and save it on your machine and work with it there. I'm not sure if that's what you're getting at here though, any more details you can offer?

Comment: Ya thats actually what it is, there is a download button for the csv and im trying to get the csv into python rather than extracting the messy table thats displayed.  I will look into wget, thanks.

Comment: but I should specify that the issue is the fact that there is no direct url, just that code i displayed.

Comment: You're unable to right click and `Copy Link Address`? That url is all you need.

Comment: When I do that all I get is www.domain.com/subdirectory/#.  There is no easy direct link to the csv it just adds the pound sign after it.

Comment: That may be workable, if you try to `wget` and then paste that link on your command line, it should create a directory that you can cd into and view the info in some format. I mean to say that the pattern of the URL isn't necessarily invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You should try Selenium, Selenium is a suite of tools to automate web browsers across many platforms. It can do a lot thing including click button.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need SOME starting URL to feed br.open() to even start the process.

It appears that you have an aspnetForm type control there and the below code MAY serve as a bit of a starting point, even though it does not work as-is (it's a work in progress...:-).
You'll need to look at the headers and parameters via the network tab of your browser dev tools to see them.

```
 br.open("http://media.ethics.ga.gov/search/Lobbyist/Lobbyist_results.aspx?&Year=2016&LastName="+letter+"&FirstName=&City=&FilerID=")
soup = BS(br.response().read())

table = soup.find("table", { "id" : "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Results" })   # Need to add error check here...
if table is None:    # No lobbyist with last name starting with 'X' :-)
   continue
records = table.find_all('tr')        # List of all results for this letter

for form in br.forms():
    print "Form name:", form.name
    print form

for row in records: 
    rec_print = ""
    span = row.find_all('span', 'lblentry', 'value')
    for sname in span:
        if ',' in sname.get_text():    # They actually have a field named 'comma'!!
            continue
        rec_print = rec_print + sname.get_text() + ","   # Create comma-delimited output
    print(rec_print[:-1])    # Strip final comma

    lnk = row.find('a', 'lblentrylink')
    if lnk is None:   # For some reason, first record is blank. 
        continue
    print("Lnk: ", lnk)
    newlnk = lnk['id'] 
    print("NEWLNK: ", newlnk)
    newstr = lnk['href']
    newctl = newstr[+25:-5]  # Matching placeholder (strip javascript....)
    br.select_form('aspnetForm')  # Tried (nr=0) also...
    print("NEWCTL: ", newctl)
    br[__EVENTTARGET] = newctl
    response = br.submit(name=newlnk).read()
```